# Vietnamese characters in sql select like

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I search with the following query

```
Select * From [table] WHERE Name like '%Hà Nội T&T%'
```

in my mssql database I get **`no results`**, even though I'm sure it exists in the db.

I seem to have trouble with characters like **`ộ, ẫ, and Đ`**.

I have tried changing collation-settings but nothing helps.

Any suggestions?

Comment: its possibly the [syntax of your query](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) .Try `Select * From '%Hà Nội T&T%'`

Comment: the collation is "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS". I have also tried "Vietnamese_CI_AS"

Comment: That column in your table ought to be of type `nvarchar(n)` and then you should query like this: `WHERE Name LIKE N'%Hà Nội T&T%'` - note the leading `N` before the string literal, telling SQL Server that this is a **Unicode** string literal

Comment: that N made the difference - thanks alot. How do I close the thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
Select * From [table] WHERE Name like N'%Hà Nội T&T%'
```

Comment: What does `N` mean in above query?

Comment: It means that the string contains or may contain Unicode characters. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter your column containing Vietnamese characters.

```
ALTER TABLE [table] ALTER COLUMN name NVARCHAR(100) COLLATE Vietnamese_CI_AS
```

And then do

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE name LIKE '%Hà Nội%'
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0bb71/3)**

Answer (score 0):

Try changing connection encoding using:

```
SET character_set_client = charset_name;
```

Also please do not use Latin1 encoding, try switching to UTF8. Here is a FAQ for Vietnamse Unicode: http://vietunicode.sourceforge.net/main.html