# Cyrillic symbols in SQL code are not correctly after insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, c#-4.0, collation

I use SQL Server 2005 and I am try to store Cyrillic characters but I can't with SQL code by trying to run this is SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO Assembly VALUES('Македонски парлиамент број 1','','');
```

Or from C# is happening the same problem but inserting/updating the column from SQL Server it work and it is store normally.

The datatype of column is `nvarchar`.

Comment: You have to use nvarchar/nchar data type plus the N prefix: `... values(N'парлиамент');`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to add N prefix before your string.

When you implicitly declare a string variable it is treated as varchar by default. Adding prefix N denotes that the subsequent string is in Unicode (nvarchar).

```
 INSERT INTO Assembly VALUES(N'Македонски парлиамент број 1','','');
```

Here is some reading:

http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-some-sql-strings-have-an-n-prefix.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186939.aspx

[What is the meaning of the prefix N in T-SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are doing a static stored procedure or scripting, but maybe the text is not being encoded properly when you save it to disk.  I ran into this, and my problem was solved in PowerShell by correcting the encoding of the SQL that I saved to disk for osql processing:

```
     Out-File -FilePath "MyFile.sql" -InputObject $MyRussianSQL -Encoding "Unicode" -Force;
     & osql -U myuser -P password -i "MyFile.sql";
```