# Why can I store an Ukrainian string in a varchar column?

Tags: sql-server, unicode, multilingual

I got a little surprised as I was able to store an Ukrainian string in a `varchar` column .

My table is:

```
create table delete_collation
(
   text1 varchar(100) collate SQL_Ukrainian_CP1251_CI_AS
)
```

and using this query I am able to insert:

```
insert into delete_collation
values(N'використовується для вирішення квитки')
```

but when I am removing `'N'` it is showing `??????` in the select statement.

Is it okay or am I missing something in understanding unicode and non-unicode with collate?

Comment: why don't just use Unicode?

Comment: i am going to use unicode only.just want to clear some doubts regarding DBCS and unicode.

Comment: if you're in doubt, read [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: excellent article..thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186939.aspx):

> Prefix Unicode character string constants with the letter `N`. Without
>   the `N` prefix, the string is converted to the default code page of the
>   database. This default code page may not recognize certain characters.

**UPDATE:** 
Please see a similar questions::
[What is the meaning of the prefix N in T-SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10025032/4275342)
[Cyrillic symbols in SQL code are not correctly after insert](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16762021/4275342)
[sql server 2012 express do not understand Russian letters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18325680/4275342)

Comment: what you mean by default code page.is it code page defined in my collate of column or defined for the daabase

Comment: for the daabase: `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')`

Answer (score 4):

To expand on MegaTron's answer:

Using `collate SQL_Ukrainian_CP1251_CI_AS`, SQL server is able to store ukrainian characters in a `varchar` column by using CodePage 1251.

However, when you specify a string without the `N` prefix, that string will be converted to the default non-unicode codepage before it is sent to the database, and that is why you see `??????`.

So it is completely fine to use `varchar` and collate as you do, but you must always include the `N` prefix when sending strings to the database, to avoid the intermediate conversion to default (non-ukrainian) codepage.