# SQL Server T-SQL N prefix on string literal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

It's maybe a noob question but I found some T-SQL query example to verify database size with `SELECT` and `WHERE` clause [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx)

Here is the code:

```
SELECT name, size, size*1.0/128 AS [Size in MBs] 
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE name = N'mytest';
```

My question is what does the `N` prefix mean in the `WHERE name = N'keyword'` clause?

I always use `WHERE name = 'keyword'` before, and I don't find the differences (you can try it by yourself).

I've googled that but I don't know the keyword I supposed to search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's declaring the string as nvarchar data type (Unicode), rather than varchar (8-bit encoding, including ASCII).

FYI, this is a duplicate of the question: 
[What is the meaning of the prefix N in T-SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements)

Comment: This is not quite correct.  Varchar is not ASCII.  Varchar is an 8 bit encoding. It can store ASCII, or it can store any other 8 bit code page for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-some-sql-strings-have-an-n-prefix.html):-

> You may have seen Transact-SQL code that passes strings around using
>   an N prefix. **This denotes that the subsequent string is in Unicode
>   (the N actually stands for National language character set).** Which
>   means that you are passing an NCHAR, NVARCHAR or NTEXT value, as
>   opposed to CHAR, VARCHAR or TEXT.

Answer (score 2):

N means there can be some unicode characters in the given string.

Answer (score 1):

It means unicode. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399176.aspx To declare a character string literal as Unicode, prefix the literal with an uppercase "N"