# Stored procedure with variables not working

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I call the procedure with php and the relevant variables. I need the latest IDs to use it for the next insert, so I set variables with SCOPE_IDENTITY. The return ist always the value of appointment_id ?!

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[insertPersonWithCmoFmo]
@appointment_id int,
@kostenstelle varchar(50),
@vorname varchar(50),
@nachname varchar(50),

@ci_nummer int,
@anzahl_monitore_old int,
@raum varchar(50),
@gebäude varchar(50),
@bemerkung text,

@hardware_typ varchar(50),
@anzahl_monitore_new varchar(50),
@zubehör text

as

DECLARE
@latestPersonID int,
@latestCmoID int,
@latestFmoID int

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO [RC.Persons] (kostenstelle, vorname, nachname) VALUES (@kostenstelle, @vorname, @nachname);
    SET @latestPersonID = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())

    INSERT INTO [RC.CMO] (ci_nummer, anzahl_monitore, raum, gebäude, bemerkung) values (@ci_nummer, @anzahl_monitore_old, @raum, @gebäude, @bemerkung);
    SET @latestCmoID = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())

    INSERT INTO [RC.FMO] (hardware_typ, anzahl_monitore, zubehör) values (@hardware_typ, @anzahl_monitore_new, @zubehör);
    SET @latestFmoID = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())

    INSERT INTO [RC.Appointments_RC.CMO] (cmo_id, appointment_id) values (@latestCmoID, @appointment_id);

    INSERT INTO [RC.Persons_RC.CMO] (cmo_id, person_id) VALUES (@latestCmoID, @latestPersonID);

    INSERT INTO [RC.Persons_RC.FMO] (fmo_id, person_id) VALUES (@latestFmoID, @latestPersonID);

    return @latestFmoID

END
```

This is the exec code. Why the is a "N" before all varchar type?

```
USE [Testtable]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[insertPersonWithCmoFmo]
        @appointment_id = 52,
        @kostenstelle = N'54',
        @vorname = N'testname',
        @nachname = N'testlastname',
        @ci_nummer = 111222333,
        @anzahl_monitore_old = 2,
        @raum = N'255',
        @gebäude = N'KWA12',
        @bemerkung = N'blablabla',
        @hardware_typ = N'Desktop',
        @anzahl_monitore_new = N'4',
        @zubehör = N'Test'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

SQL Output:
Meldung 2601, Ebene 14, Status 1, Prozedur insertPersonWithCmoFmo, Zeile 36
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.RC.FMO' with unique index 'NonClusteredIndex-20140116-143317'. The duplicate key value is ().
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: [Please use an output parameter or a resultset instead of `RETURN` for pulling data back from your procedure. `RETURN` is for error/status codes](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-or-return-instead-of-output). Also, don't use `single quotes` for alias delimiters - this syntax is deprecated in some scenarios, and makes your column look like a string literal. If you must use an alias that requires delimiting (hint: you should avoid it), use `[square brackets]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there something about the error message you don't understand?  One or more of the tables has a unique constraint (or index) and you are trying to insert the same values in the table.  For example, the `persons` table might already have the person in it.

The `N` before the string explicitly makes the string use wide characters.

Your stored procedure probably needs to be rewritten.  You need to check errors that might occur along the way.  Traditionally, a value would be returned using an `OUTPUT` parameter.

The safest way to get the new `id` value is to use the `output` clause of the `insert` statement (see the documentation [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)).

Comment: The ids are all auto increments. So I dont understand why there can be dublicate ids in a table.

Comment: @mnlfischer . . . The duplicates are not on the auto incremented ids.  There might be a unique index, for instance, on `hardware_typ, anzahl_monitore, zubehör` and you are inserting duplicates there.  (The problem is on the `FMO` table.)

Answer (score 0):

The N indicates nvarchar instead of varchar.

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements