# SQL syntax error (SQL injection)

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am having a class in computer security and are having a little trouble with the syntax when doing a sql injection on a local machine that we are suppose to hack.

below is the syntax of the sql syntax.

```
SqlCommand sqlc = new SqlCommand("SELECT Record FROM Table_Users WHERE Username='" + username + "' AND Password='" + password + "'");
```

We are trying the following in the login (username) field and ' or '1'='1 in the password

```
;INSERT Table_Users (Username, Password) VALUES ('hejsan', 'glenn');
```

But am getting a syntax error "Incorrect syntax near 'hejsan'."

Can you see the syntax error? =)

Comment: Can you be a little more clear on what your _exact_ input is?  It's a little unclear when it's inline with the question.

Comment: Also, am I the only one uncomfortable providing tips on proper SQL injection?  Has anyone else ever heard of a class that teaches _how_ to do it?

Comment: He's not asking how to do sql injection(although the code sample is certainly prone to it), it's just a bad Insert statement.

Comment: I want to cancel "Username='""' and then start a new sql insert after that and comment out whatever comes after "Insert Table_users"

Comment: @gts Read the first sentence - (also the `INSERT` statement is not bad - the `INTO` keyword is optional).

Comment: @andres - Hint - what should the first character be to close out the `Username='` statement?

Comment: @DStanley my bad, I had a bad choice of wording, by 'asking' I meant what he is after rather what he is literally asking. Also updated answer with alt solution

Comment: We are teached this in class because this is easily fixed by just checking the user input which might be missed otherwise, but your concern is justified =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
 ';INSERT Table_Users (Username, Password) VALUES ('hejsan', 'glenn');
```

-> you need to close the `'` after `Username=`.
In this case you don't even need a value for the password field.

You could put `--` after your injected statement to cancel the rest of the select statement:

```
';INSERT Table_Users (Username, Password) VALUES ('hejsan', 'glenn');--
```

Answer (score 4):

My first take was to have
`INSERT INTO Table_Users` instead of `INSERT Table_Users` but as the poster noted `INTO` is optional(in MSSQL in contrast to the standard ANSI SQL).

On second thought depending on what the data type your columns are the query could work by appending N in front of the values as per [What is the meaning of the prefix N in T-SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements)

Comment: `INTO` is optional.  That's not the problem.

Comment: Updated answer with alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

maybe something with the quotes?

`var password = "';INSERT Table_Users (Username, Password) VALUES (''hejsan'', ''glenn''); select '";`