# SQL WHERE clause does not match on columns with Latin and Thai characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, nvarchar, thai

I'm cleaning up a SQL Server 2012 database which contains some `nvarchar` columns containing mixed character set data (Latin and Thai script). For example:

[image]

As I have a number of columns with the same *TariffDescription* text, I want to apply a translation using a simple UPDATE command. For example:

```
UPDATE Tariff.NationalTariff 
SET TariffDescription = 'Liquid.' 
WHERE TariffDescription = 'Thai description: - - ที่มีสภาพเหลว';
```

However, when I execute this command, SQL Server is not updating any rows. I confirmed that the problem is with the WHERE clause by attempting to do a simple select:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tariff.NationalTariff 
WHERE TariffDescription = 'Thai description: - - ที่มีสภาพเหลว';
```

This query returns zero rows when I expected it to return around a hundred or so.

Note that I populated the WHERE clause string by copying and pasting from the Results table (using a query that does not rely on the *TariffDescription* column). I cannot type in Thai characters.

I have no idea why this is happening and my best guess is that it has something to do with mixing together character sets. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place N before the literal text

```
   SELECT * FROM Tariff.NationalTariff WHERE TariffDescription = N'Thai description: - - ที่มีสภาพเหลว';
```

Comment: Yes, this fixes the problem. Thank-you. I did a quick google on the N prefix before a string in T-SQL which designates it as an NVARCHAR string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements