# What does N and U stand for and what are its meaning while finding an object

Tags: sql-server

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.AWBuildVersion', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.AWBuildVersion;
```

I don't understand what N and U are for in SQL server ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements

Comment: For `'U'`, see the [`OBJECT_ID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx) documentation, which links in turn to the [`sys.objects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx) documentation.

Comment: I personally would recommend rewriting this query as `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE Name = N'AWBuildVersion')` - use the more focused `sys.tables` and so on catalog views to detect existance of an object

Answer (score 13):

- `U` stands for `Table (user-defined).` Check **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190324.aspx)** for more info. The syntax `OBJECT_ID` is

  ```
  OBJECT_ID ( '[ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] 
  object_name' [ ,'object_type' ] )
  ```

  here `Object_type = 'U'` which denotes `Table (user-defined)`
- `N` Makes the String to be considered as `nvarchar data type`. It denotes that the subsequent string is in Unicode (the N
        actually stands for National language character set). Which means
        that you are passing an NCHAR, NVARCHAR or NTEXT value, as opposed
        to CHAR, VARCHAR or TEXT.

Answer (score 4):

`'U'` character stands for itself. The `N` prefix makes it a one-character [UNICODE string.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) OBJECT_ID procedure expects you to pass one of pre-defined one-character values for the second parameter, which needs to be a UNICODE string.

This syntax is used to create literals with characters in other encodings, for example

```
CREATE TABLE hello_world (str NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO hello_world (str) VALUES (N'Здравствуй, мир!')
```

Comment: I thought `U` stands for `User table`

Comment: No, it stands for 'U' which is a paramter for the function called. WHat it means is not what it stands for - the MEANING of passing an U in this parameter is... documented... in the documentation.

Comment: @TomTom You should have made it explicit that you are replying to M.Ali. It looks like people misinterpret your comment as a disagreement with my answer.