# What is the use of writing N' ' in query sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am using `sql-server 2012` and I have this query

```
create table t
( 
id int not null,
name varchar(10)
);


select OBJECT_NAME(object_id) as table_name,type,name as table_name,type_dec
from sys.indexes
where object_id=OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.t',N'U')
```

whats the difference in `object_id and OBJECT_ID`
and what is the use of writing `N''`

The query returns same result: with or without `N`
[image]

Comment: If you mark the keyword you are curious about and hit `shift+f1` you'll get the documentation for that keyword and all the answers you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of the prefix N in T-SQL statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements)

Comment: @HareRamaHareKrishna any feedback on this ?

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, the prefix `N'` is used to specify a `nvarchar` type, which stands for national character.

From the doc :

> Prefix Unicode character string constants with the letter N. Without
>   the N prefix, the string is converted to the default code page of the
>   database. This default code page may not recognize certain characters.

In other world, it is an unicode character.

Answer (score 0):

The `N` in `N'xxx'` means "national language", denoting a unicode string.

If you use it to store data into a `VARCHAR` as opposed to a `NVARCHAR` column, it has little use.

You can read more about it under the "Unicode strings" sub-heading on this page: [Constants (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**: Object_id and OBJECT_ID are one and the same.

**Q2** is already answered [here][1]