# N used in msdb param values

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is `N` in `=N'...'` mentioned in the example [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182079(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
USE msdb ;
GO

EXEC dbo.sp_add_job
@job_name = N'Ad hoc Sales Data Backup', 
@enabled = 1,
@description = N'Ad hoc backup of sales data',
@owner_login_name = N'françoisa',
@notify_level_eventlog = 2,
@notify_level_email = 2,
@notify_level_netsend = 2,
@notify_level_page = 2,
@notify_email_operator_name = N'François Ajenstat',
@notify_netsend_operator_name = N'François Ajenstat', 
@notify_page_operator_name = N'François Ajenstat',
@delete_level = 1 ;
GO
```

Comment: @wewesthemenace also thought the same..so this is to tell msdb proc which kind of data we are going to enter?

Comment: Yes, you could also remove the `N` but that will put an additional cost for conversion. also @Patrick Hofman's answer.

Comment: @wewesthemenace and it is going to construct the tables accordingly?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you talking about the `sp_add_job`?

Comment: @wewesthemenace sorry wrong context..let say for `sysmail_allitems`..and if we use N in the proc while exec `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` and passing param with `N`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database can't see the difference between a `varchar` literal and a `nvarchar` literal. When you put in a string (`'abc'`), it doesn't know you actually meant this to be unicode. (This is very important sometimes to get the right encoding, for example when using Arabic or Greek characters.)

The `N` string literal prefix will indicate that string is a unicode literal.

Comment: yes..thanks for asking..let say for sysmail_allitems..and if we use N in the proc while exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail and passing param with N

Comment: Yes, all parameters will be passed as unicode strings.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with Unicode string constants in SQL Server you must precede all Unicode strings with a capital letter N, as documented in the SQL Server Books Online topic "Using Unicode Data". The "N" prefix stands for National Language in the SQL-92 standard, and must be uppercase. If you do not prefix a Unicode string constant with N, SQL Server will convert it to the non-Unicode code page of the current database before it uses the string.

It's declaring the string as `nvarchar` data type, rather than `varchar`.

check out this.The following articles have some good information on the question

http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-some-sql-strings-have-an-n-prefix.html http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/239530

Answer (score 0):

That `N'..'` means the parameter is `nvarchar` data type

Answer (score 0):

It's declaring the string as `nvarchar` data type, rather than `varchar` [Here Is Best Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements)