# Sales report in SQL Server 2008 merging same year into one?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following query to display sales report in each year and month

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(orderDate) as SalesYear,
         MONTH(orderDate) as SalesMonth,
         SUM(Price) AS TotalSales
    FROM Sales
GROUP BY YEAR(orderDate),MONTH(orderDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(orderDate), MONTH(orderDate)
```

output

```
2013    2   350.00
2013    5   350.00
2014    8   30.00
2014    11  30.00
2015    1   350.00
2015    8   120.00
```

But I need?
 output like:

```
    2013    2   700.00  
    2014    2   60.00
    2015    2   470.00
```

Note: The **month part** should be the total number of months in each year.

Any help?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table  sales (orderdate date, price money);

insert into sales values
(N'2013-02-01', 350.00), 
(N'2013-05-01', 350.00),
(N'2014-08-01', 30.00),
(N'2014-11-01', 30.00),
(N'2015-01-01', 350.00),
(N'2015-08-01', 120.00);
```

Alternatively, you could also use window functions `SUM() OVER` and `COUNT() OVER` to do this:

```
SELECT distinct
      YEAR(orderDate) as SalesYear,
      count(MONTH(orderDate)) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(OrderDate))  as SalesMonth,
      SUM(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(OrderDate)) AS TotalSales
FROM Sales
ORDER BY YEAR(orderDate);
```

**Result:**

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
| SalesYear | SalesMonth | TotalSales |
+-----------+------------+------------+
|      2013 |          2 |        700 |
|      2014 |          2 |         60 |
|      2015 |          2 |        470 |
+-----------+------------+------------+
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d73ec/4/0)

Comment: I am very interested in your solution with the concept Partition by. Now I have searched for it and understood. But what is the 'N' which you put while inserting values to sales table? thanks again!

Comment: @NurSelam Excellent! I am glad that you were interested in my solution. The `N` is just a way of declaring the date string as `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`. Here is a good explanation on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your output from your first query you need something like

```
  SELECT YEAR, Count(Month), Sum(TotalSales)
    FROM Sales
    GROUP BY YEAR
```

so

```
    SELECT 
    YEAR(orderDate) as SalesYear,
         Count(MONTH(orderDate)) as SalesMonthCount,
         SUM(Price) AS TotalSales
    FROM Sales
    GROUP BY YEAR(orderDate)
    ORDER BY YEAR(orderDate)
```

Comment: you accidentally put a comma in your group by.

Comment: Thanks, I must have fat fingers today.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
      YEAR(orderDate) as SalesYear,
      count(MONTH(orderDate)) as SalesMonth,
      SUM(Price) AS TotalSales
FROM Sales
GROUP BY YEAR(orderDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(orderDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly simple thing to do. Since you want the Count of months, just do that instead. The distinct is key for the month count unless you are just trying to count total orders, in which case you should just count Price and save processing time.

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(orderDate) as SalesYear,
         Count(Distinct Month(orderDate)) as SalesMonth,
         SUM(Price) AS TotalSales
    FROM Sales
GROUP BY YEAR(orderDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(orderDate)
```