# What is the meaning of an "N" before quotes in a SQL Server assignment?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The code I am looking at is this:

```
        SET @Message = N'Question result is ''' + @CurrentResult + '''. It should be unmarked or incorrect';
        THROW 50002,@Message,1
```

Can someone explain why the developer but "N" before the quotes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186939.aspx) in *remarks* section

Saying that string is of `Nvarchar` type and can have *unicode* charcters

> Prefix Unicode character string constants with the letter N. Without
>   the N prefix, the string is converted to the default code page of the
>   database. This default code page may not recognize certain characters.

The `"N"` prefix stands for National Language in the SQL-92 standard, and must be uppercase. If you do not prefix a Unicode string constant with N, SQL Server will convert it to the non-Unicode code page of the current database before it uses the string.

Here is more detailed information

[You must precede all Unicode strings with a prefix N when you deal with Unicode string constants in SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/239530)