# executing external scripts in sql

Tags: sql, r

I am just trying to write codes in R-Script in SQL but I am getting this error. Can anyone please help

```sql
execute sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'R',
@script = N'
 
install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)
authorshtml <- read_html("https://www.mssqltips.com/sql-server-mssqltips-authors/")
authors <- authorshtml %>% html_nodes("div .large-7") %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_text() 
OutputDataSet <- data.frame(authors)
 
'
with result sets ((Authors varchar(max)))
```

but I get this error nd cant seem to figure it out.

```
Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 0
A 'R' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 0
An external script error occurred: 
Error in eval(ei, envir) : object 'N' not found
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval

Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
Error in eval(ei, envir) : 
  Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
Calls: runScriptFile -> source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> .Call
Execution halted
```

Comment: I think the `N'...'` nomenclature is to protect unicode varchars (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35671587/3358272). You might try without the leading `N` (just `@script = '...'`), though that should be just a troubleshooting step, not a permanent change to your query/process.

Comment: I've tried that and didn't seem to make much difference. Now it doesn't seem to recognize the library command as well as the package (RVEST) which has been downloaded