# Is there a way to find and update data type for all dummy columns in all stored procedures in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I have 200 stored procedures and many of them have `SELECT` statements with dummy columns like this:

```
SELECT 'Label' 
FROM myTable;
```

I want to use `CAST` function to change dummy columns' datatype to `NVARCHAR`.

I don't want to go through each and every stored procedure and do it manually.

Is there a way to do this in bulk?

Comment: are all the dummy columns defined as `Label` ?

Comment: thanks for responding so quickly. Not all the dummy columns have the same name, they are all different.

Comment: Well unless you can come up with a list of dummy columns I dont think there is a possible way of telling SQL Server what columns to change, It is maybe a dummy column for you but for SQL Server its like an other column.

Comment: yes, makes sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: I dont think there is an automated way of doing this. If you save your SPs as text files (can be done in bulk), you should be able to use regular expressions to find your dummy columns. Depending on your exact requirements all you need to do is add "N" to the beginning of the string ("SELECT N'Label' From myTable;"). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements