# When chinese word in mysql where statement

Tags: php

[how to select 主页报修上广告](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOLgX.png)

```
$sql = "SELECT text,pic FROM newstable where type='在线报修上广告' order by id desc limit 0,1";
```

but you may find the return value is null

But i try to use this

```
$sql = "SELECT text,pic FROM newstable where type=N'在线报修上广告' order by id desc limit 0,1";
```

there is N before '在线报修上广告' ------->>>>>but it works....what's the meaning of this 'N'!!

Answer (score 2):

[What is the meaning of the prefix N in T-SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements)

It#s declaring your varchar as nvarchar which is using a unicode encoding page. Otherwise it will be converted to the default encoding page of your database. Basically it's prefered to use only varchar when intended (like email addresses)