# Entity Framework procedure is not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, procedure

When I run this code and watch in SQL Server Profiler, there is no return value

```
exec [dbo].[p_PersonelEkleAgiGetir] 
     @MedeniDurum = N'Evli',
     @CocukSayisi = 0,
     @EsCalismaDurumu = N'Çalışmıyor'
```

I erased the `N` from in front of the parameters and then it works. What do I have to do for this to work in the code?

This is my entity procedure code

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<decimal>> p_PersonelEkleAgiGetir(string medeniDurum, Nullable<int> cocukSayisi, string esCalismaDurumu)
{
    var medeniDurumParameter = medeniDurum != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("MedeniDurum", medeniDurum) :
        new ObjectParameter("MedeniDurum", typeof(string));

    var cocukSayisiParameter = cocukSayisi.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("CocukSayisi", cocukSayisi) :
        new ObjectParameter("CocukSayisi", typeof(int));

    var esCalismaDurumuParameter = esCalismaDurumu != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("EsCalismaDurumu", esCalismaDurumu) :
        new ObjectParameter("EsCalismaDurumu", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<decimal>>("p_PersonelEkleAgiGetir", medeniDurumParameter, cocukSayisiParameter, esCalismaDurumuParameter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question well, you want to know why deleting the `N`s makes it run correctly but with the `N`s it doesn't run. The `N` indicates that the string is a `Unicode`. When you erase them, the procedure accepts it because it accepts non-Unicode strings. You can see more information here:

[What is the meaning of the prefix N in T-SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements)