# AM/PM are saved as ?? without SQL N prefix

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I usually use N prefix in inserting data into sql server table when the data are not in English however when I want to save current time the AM or PM while be saved as `??` when I don't use `N prefix`.

This is how I save time in database here mtime is `nvarchar(50)`:

```
<%
t=time
sql=insert into notes (body,mtime) values (N'" & body &"','"& t &"')"
Con.execute sql
%>
```

why do I need N prefix to save time? isn't output of `asp time`, a string in English characters?

Comment: Does this happen via SSMS? BTW, _Latin_ you mean instead of english.

Comment: You desperately need to read about and start using parameterized queries. Your code is wide open to sql injection. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: And why in the world is mtime nvarchar(50)? You should use the time datatype to store time information.

Comment: No. This happen only to asp TIME function @Sami

Comment: This code would produce a syntax error.   Please post your actual code, and post the value of `t` that produces the `??` result.   The problem you say you are having is not reproducible based on what you have posted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in IIS manager that the Locale of ASP was not set and so the time was being generated in Farsi language like 12:00 ق.ظ instead of 12:00 AM. I did two things and not sure if both of them was mandatory:

1. IIS manager > Choose server > ASP > Locale ID : 1033 (code for English US)
2. Changing locale of Master Database  from Arabic to Latin using [this instruction](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3519/changing-sql-server-collation-after-installation/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need to store the `AM/PM` as `STRING`, all what you need is to choose the right `DataType` which is in your case `TIME`.

After you store some data, then it's easy:)

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
    MyTime TIME
    );

INSERT INTO Test VALUES
('08:00:00'),
('13:00:00');

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), MyTime,100) AS TheTimeIs
FROM Test;
```

Results:

```
+-----------+
| TheTimeIs |
+-----------+
| 8:00AM    |
| 1:00PM    |
+-----------+
```

Bside to this it seems like you also confuse about the `N'` prefix, when and why we should use it, here is a **[Good answer about that prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10025043/6426692)**.

Comment: I get the time using asp TIME function and so I don't want to convert it to other formats.