# Linq Dynamics adds an N to my parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, parameters, entity-framework-6

I'm working on custom filter with `System.Linq.Dynamic`, everything was ok until i start the fight with `BETWEEN`.

I created a custom class called `Filtro`, it has this propertys .

```
public string PropertyName { get; set; }
public string Value1 { get; set; }
public string Value2 { get; set; }
```

Then, i basically filter a `IQueryable` object with the parameters of that class

I'm trying this:

```
var query = db.Where("@0 > @1 AND @0 < @2", filtro.PropertyName, filtro.Value1, filtro.Value2);
```

My problem is that the parameters are generated incorrectly in the query.

Example:

```
filtro.PropertyName = "example";
filtro.Value1 = "10";
filtro.Value2 = "20";
```

When i generate query without parameters

```
var query = db.Where("example>10 && example<20");
```

It generates this:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[randomField] AS [randomField], 
    [Extent1].[example] AS [example], 
    FROM [dbo].[Transformador] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[example] > cast(10 as decimal(18))) AND ([Extent1].[example] < cast(20 as decimal(18)))
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[randomField] ASC}
```

But when i use parameters (as i show before) i'm getting this

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[randomField] AS [randomField], 
    [Extent1].[example] AS [example]
    FROM [dbo].[Transformador] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (N'example' > N'10') AND (N'example' < N'20')
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[randomField] ASC
```

I guess I'm using the parameters of Linq Dynamics wrong, but I did not find anything similar going around on the internet

I hope someone know what the problem is, thanks in advance!

Comment: What is wrong with the `N'` prefix? That's [perfectly normal SQL syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements). Is it causing your queries to fail?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements

Comment: @DavidG the query's return 0 rows :S

Comment: @PeterBons the wierd thing is normal Linq dont add's the `N` character, probably, the problem is it doesn't recognize, the second and third parameters as number, if i pass them as numbers, it thrown an exception :S

Comment: Yeah seems illogical. Anyway, I wouldn't give it much thought. There is nothing going wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Dynamic Linq is assuming the `example` value you are passing in is a *value* and not a *column* name. So the query returns no rows because the string `example` is not between the strings `10` and `20`.

The `N'` prefix is perfectly normal SQL syntax and is only coercing the string into an `NVARCHAR` type instead of `VARCHAR`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements) for more info. For you code however, try this for example:

```
var sql = $"{filtro.PropertyName} > @0 AND {filtro.PropertyName} < @1";
var query = db.Where(sql, filtro.Value1, filtro.Value2);
```

Note: this leaves you open to SQL injection so is quite dangerous.

Comment: Thank you! But, is there another solution to avoid sql injection? Could you guide me to investigate?

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with Dynamic Linq unfortunately, I prefer to use `Expression`s.