# Underscore "_" auto change to Questions Marks "?"

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I facing one issue on my website.

**Problem**: The underscore "_" some time will automatically change to Questions Marks "?".

**Example as below**:

Below are my original filename

[image]

After saving into the database, the file name will automatically change as below. You may notice some of the underscores changed to question mark.

[image]

This problem is created by my user.
I tried to replicate the problem, but unfortunately, I failed to replicate it. 
I also tried to upload the same file, but the filename uploaded successfully as the original file name.
This is so weird that sometimes the filename is correct and sometimes not.
Can someone please enlighten me where can I start to debug with?

Additional Note:

- I am using MariaDB database
- MVC without Entity framework

Comment: It's obviously the encoding issue.

Comment: what is the data type of that particular column?

Comment: @DilanWickramarathna the datatype for that column is VARCHAR(20)

Comment: @Gleb how can I debug?

Comment: if you are using normal insert operation try to use NVARCHAR(20) as column data type and, use "N" character before the value parameter like N'your_file_name_parameter';

Comment: @DilanWickramarathna May I know what is the purpose to add in "N" character before the value? Actually this is not only happening in one column, but it also happened in other columns as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10025043/2801351 this might help you to understand

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have fallen onto the same case as [mysql here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/characters-appear-as-question-marks-using-mysql-204051027.html).

> The default encoding for inbound connections isn't set properly. DEFAULT CHARSET will return as utf8 however character_set_server will be something different.

I can't be sure about the exact problem without seeing some of your retrieval code, but [some information on MariaDB collation is here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/setting-character-sets-and-collations/)

Comment: My character_set_server is set as latin1. 
It is correct ?

Comment: I would say that you need UTF-8 to resolve such issues.

Comment: Alright. I will try to search on how to change it to utf8 and see if the problem still exists.