# Why a special character appears when i dont use N in front for the SQL procedure parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parameters, procedure

In the procedure we are just returning the value of the parameter. How ever the results are different for the following queries. Why does this hapen?

```
   exec GetItemQtyOnHand @itemCode=N'​173YU25HNBRMSB'

   exec GetItemQtyOnHand @itemCode='​173YU25HNBRMSB'
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of the prefix N in T-SQL statements and when should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements-and-when-should-i-use-it)

Comment: Side note, the first character you have is a [Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm).

Comment: Adding to @Larnu 's comment, characters in non-Unicode literals that do not exist in the collation code page are mapped to a fallback character or `?` when no similar character exists in the code page.

Comment: sp body please.

Comment: its just returning the param value