# File name with greek beta character gets changed when entered in SQL Server varchar field

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, filenames

I have a bunch of pdf files in a folder on a Windows computer. One is named *β-Alanine.pdf* (note the beta character). When I programmatically (C# .NET WinForms) read the file names using *folderInfo.EnumerateFiles("*.pdf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)* and insert the file name in a
varchar field of a SQL Server table, the file name gets changed to *ß-Alanine.pdf* (note the different beta character). Of course, when I subsequently read the file name from the DB and then use a method like File.Exists(filename) it fails. I'm at a loss here as to what to do to fix this other than asking people not to use Greek characters in the file name. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did you try to use NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR ?

Comment: Using NVARCHAR did the trick. Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of the prefix N in T-SQL statements and when should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements-and-when-should-i-use-it)

Comment: Your link provides useful information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using NVARCHAR as suggested by Sergey resolved the problem.