# How to check a cast from nvarchar to varbinary in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have an old database named `OldData` with data that I want to pass to my new database named `School`. I have a problem with my check on my database creating script. The column in question from old database is of type `nvarchar` and I want to cast it to `varbinary`.

My column creation:

```
studentFamSize VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

I want to check if my `varbinary` column is N'LE3' or N'GT3', my check currently is like this:

```
CONSTRAINT CHK_studentFamSize 
    CHECK (studentFamSize = 0x4C4533 OR studentFamSize = 0x475433)
```

And my cast:

```
CAST(famsize AS VARBINARY(100))
```

I get an error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CHK_studentFamSize". The conflict occurred in database "School", table "dbo.Student", column 'studentFamSize'.

If someone can help me, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem; a value already in the table doesn't meet the requirements of the `CONSTRAINT` so the `CONSTRAINT` can't be created.

Comment: @Larnu but I have tried this "SELECT * FROM studentBD2017 WHERE famsize not in ('LE3', 'GT3');" and I got 0 results...

Comment: `'LE3'` is a `varchar` not an `nvarchar`. In binary, `'LE3'` and `N'LE3'` are completely different values.

Comment: @Larnu it is nvarchar in my old database

Comment: Why are you storing 3 character strings as varbinary and why max?

Comment: Yes, and `0x4C4533` as an **`nvarchar`** is not `'LE3'`, it's `N'䕌3'`.

Comment: @MartinSmith I can switch that later, that's not my main problem, and its school exercise, my teacher wants binary type

Comment: So, should I compare to N'䕌3' in my check?

Comment: No, if you inserted the value `N'LE3'` into your column, then the value will be `0x4C0045003300`. Again, from a binary perspective `'LE3'` and `N'LE3'` are *very* different values (`0x4C4533` and `0x4C0045003300` respectively).

Comment: @JoãoRamos - on the contrary this is entirely the main problem. If your target column was a suitable datatype and you weren't doing an incorrect binary comparison in the check constraint you wouldn't have this issue

Comment: @Larnu Yes, in my oldData there are only 'LE3' and 'GT3' values, but as nvarchar

Comment: @Larnu its 'LE3' not N'LE3' where did you get that from?

Comment: No, it's an `nvarchar`, it's `N'LE3'`. `'LE3'` is a **`varchar`**. See [What is the meaning of the prefix N in T-SQL statements and when should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements-and-when-should-i-use-it)

Comment: @Larnu Now I understand but the datatype in my old database is nvarchar, not varchar

Comment: As @MartinSmith highlighted, this is a problem entirely of your own making. Yes `'LE3'` and `N'LE3'` will be see as equal in a comparison expression, because `'LE3'` would be implicitly converted to an `nvarchar` due to [Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). On the other hand the `varbinary` representations of those 2 values (again `0x4C4533` and `0x4C0045003300` respectively) would **not** be equal because they clearly are not.

Comment: *"Now I understand but the datatype in my old database is nvarchar, not varchar "* Then, with respect, you clearly don't. `0x4C4533 <> N'LE3'`. `0x4C4533 = 'LE3'`.

Comment: @Larnu so, LE3=0x4C4533 and GT3=0x4C0045003300 ??

Comment: No... You aren't reading the comments here. I don't know what else to say here other than you seem to think that `varchar` and `nvarchar` values are the same, they aren't... *Especially* when dealing with binary values. Fix your design, fix the problem. I'm out.

Comment: @Larnu I'm reading the comments, you are basically saying that my datatype from my old database is wrong and it should be varchar instead of nvarchar right? but i cant do nothing related to that

Comment: Nope, I didn't say that at all.

Comment: @Larnu So I didn't understand what you said...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is simple, fix your design:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN studentFamSize nvarchar(3) NOT NULL;
```

Then add the correct `CONSTRAINT`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_studentFamSize CHECK (studentFamSize IN (N'LE3', N'GT3'));
```