# SQL Server string comparison with equals sign and equals or greater in the strings

Tags: sql-server, string-comparison

I found a strange anomaly when I ran this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ProductCategories 
WHERE Name_SV = 'Fibercementskivor, byggskiva, ≤ 60 vikt-% cement,'
```

and got a result with Name_SV:

```
Fibercementskivor, byggskiva, = 60 vikt-% cement,
```

which is not equal to what I'm searching for. I then appended "AND '3≤' = '3=' " to my WHERE clause to verify that SQL Server does something weird when string comparing = and ≤ and still got a result.

What's going on here? Why is SQL Server ignoring this difference, and how can I get around this problem?

Comment: `Name_SV = N'Fibercementskivor, byggskiva, ≤ 60 vikt-% cement,'` Notice the unicode N

Comment: If you try a simple `SELECT '≤'`, you'll see that this indeed gets converted to `=`, courtesy of the collation mapping rules, since `≤` is not a character present in most non-Unicode collations. It's a bit unfortunate that it converts it this way instead of the usual `?` for unmappable characters, as that would make the issue much clearer. Using Unicode literals is the solution, per HoneyBadger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of the prefix N in T-SQL statements and when should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements-and-when-should-i-use-it)