# Store non english data in ??? format even datatype is nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

```
CREATE TABLE outvalue(name NVARCHAR(50),lastname NVARCHAR(50));
Insert into outvalue('علی','خان');
select * from outvalue;
```

Returns `????` For both columns

What is the problem with this code?
May you help me in this.

Comment: you must N "  Insert into outvalue(N'علی','خان')  "

Comment: When you specify a string literal that contains non-english unicode characters / characters outside of the normal ASCII range you need to indicate the text is *unicode* by prefixing the string with N

Comment: [What is the meaning of the prefix N in T-SQL statements and when should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements-and-when-should-i-use-it)