# Character issue on Windows Server, not on Unix (� characters)

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, prisma, collation

On my Windows Server 2019 In my NodeJS script I'm writing to the database using the Prisma library.

The field I'm adding this to is an `NVARCHAR(1000)` field. So that should accept this character, right?

The string input comes from `fs.readFileSync(customJobPath, 'utf8')`, I'm reading a txt file with the data

I have the following word `Gardé`

- Now on my local database this is saved correctly
- In my production MSSQL database, it's entered as `Gard�`

#### What I've tried

- I've checked the collation of both the database using `SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation') AS DatabaseCollation;`, and in both cases it's set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`
- When inserting an `é` character manually and saving (in Tableplus), it is saved correctly in the database.

Does anyone know if there's something I'm missing?

Comment: `I've checked the collation of both MSSQL database` - why? What you should have checked is what is the type of column you are saving it to, and whether the code that saves it [uses the `N`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10025032/11683).

Comment: An application bug tried to insert non-Unicode data using the wrong codepage. That data is lost. `�` is the Unicode replacement character, used precisely in this situation - when a character in one codepage is converted to another codepage with no matching character.

Comment: Thanks @GSerg, I updated my question, the field is an NVARCHAR(1000) field. What do you mean with "the N"?

Comment: We know that the field is `nvarchar`, because you got the � character. Strings in JavaScript are Unicode. That means that the *query code* either used the wrong string type explicitly, or used string concatenation to generate a query instead of a parameterized query. In that query, the text data was passed without the `N` prefix that denotes Unicode strings.

Comment: @MiguelStevens post the application code. That's where the bug is. The correct solution is to use queries with parameters, not string concatenation or interpolation. Apart from such errors, this exposes you to SQL injection attacks. Imagine what would happen if someone entered `'; DROP TABLE USERS;--`

Comment: @miguel stevens - As u mentioned that manual entry in DB works fine. Thus, it Seems like Application layer error. Did u check what entry is getting passed to server before going to DB

Comment: @ViralJain That's good idea, I'll try and find out if Prisma is the culprit.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using the default Prisma create method: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#create

Comment: Please avoid using "txt spk", @ViralJain . It can be confusing enough for native English speaking people at times, and for non-natives it can honestly make the sentence look like nonsense; we're not in a world where you're limited to 160 characters per message.

Comment: Can you share the code for your [data model](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model)? It could be that you are missing some [native type mapping](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model#native-types-mapping). Based on the documentation you need to use `@db.NVarChar(x)` so that the correct parameter types are generated.

Comment: @MiguelStevens using what input? Did it come from a browser? A local file? Please post code that actually reproduces the problem. JS strings are Unicode, so if you typed the text yourself in JS, there would be no problem. Almost all web pages and APIs use UTF8, so that wouldn't be an issue either. `é` is in Latin1, which is the default on most *developer* machines.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Good question! The string comes from parsing a TXT file on the server using `fs.readFileSync(customJobPath, 'utf8')`, Could this be the reason? EDIT: Updated question

Comment: Does the value appear correct in your text file? Is the encoding utf8 for the text file? If so then the next step is to share the relevant code in your question. Better yet, create an [mcve]

Comment: I found a solution, using 'latin1' for the readFileSync, instead of utf-8. Still wonder why this does work locally with 'utf-8'

Comment: Because the local file is in utf8?

Comment: This can only work if the local file was saved as UTF8. Characters in the range 0x00-0x7F range are encoded using the *same* single byte in all codepages. Characters above that are encoded using two or more bytes. You'd see two or more `?` if you tried to read a UTF8 file with the wrong encoding. The ideal solution is to ensure files are always in UTF8, not try to guess the encoding.

Comment: Is this on Windows or Linux?

Comment: can't you use an UTF8 collation ? Even with a stagging table ?? The collation of your database can be different from the collation of a column in the table. Check the collation of the columns via the view INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS...

Comment: @jarlh I forgot to mention, and added to my question, the error was happening on a Windows server, with the 'latin1' enconding the issue is fixed on windows server, on my mac however, the problem now arose. So I guess it's a platform issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information in the question to be sure, but I suspect you have one (or more) of four issues:

1. You're using string concatenation or interpolation to include this data in the query. This would already be wrong (you should be using query parameters), but specifically for this issue you could additionally fail if you do not include the `N` prefix for the literal... if you have `'Gardé'` in the SQL string instead of `N'Gardé'`. The former is first interpreted as a basic `varchar` value, so the non-ASCII characters are lost. The latter is correctly interpreted as an `nvarchar`.
2. You're using parameterized queries (as you should), but setting the parameter type to `varchar` instead of `nvarchar` (perhaps implicitly, by failing to explicitly type the parameter). Again, in this situation the value is first processed as a `varchar` where the non-ASCII symbols are lost, before saving to the `nvarchar` field.
3. Javascript has weak handling of Unicode, and you're loading the string from the file to the nodejs string in a way that fails to preserve the original character, before then passing it on to SQL. (Hint: just because we told the `readFileSync()` method we needed utf8, it doesn't mean the string variable we assigned the result to was able to correctly receive this result.)
4. The original file is not actually stored in UTF-8, but rather UTF-16, full Unicode, or some other format with wide character support, such that interpreting it as UTF-8 mangles the character.