# PDO quoting integers in the query.What should I do now?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356206/mysql-pdoquote-putting-single-quotes-around-integers).I have the following queries

```
$start=150;
$sql='select * from articles where category=? limit ?,5';
$query=$con->prepare($sql)
$query->execute(array($_GET['category'],$start));
```

and I am getting the error (due to quoting of 150):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ''150',5' at line 1.

This has been reported as a bug and later closed as bogus.What should I do now?Is there any workaround?

**EDIT**

Why I do not run into the same issue, when I have a query like

```
$sql='select * from articles where id=?';
$query=$con->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array($id));
```

Comment: It isn't an issue when binding against `id=?` because MySQL doesn't care if that is quoted.  The solution to using it in `LIMIT` as identified both in the answer below and in the linked question is to explicitly `bindParam()` to force `PDO::PARAM_INT` instead of passing an array to `execute()` which will send strings (and quote them)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: and why is that so special.Shouldn't the behaviour be same in every case.Is the quotes acceptable in case of Primary key columns coz in place of `id` it could have been `user_id` and it still works with quotes around integer?

Comment: That's a question for MySQL developers. `LIMIT` is MySQL-specific, not implemented in all other RDBMS.  You may get different results if you have emulated prepares enabled, and disable it in PDO.

Answer (score 4):

As `PDOStatement::execute` documentation says, *"All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR."* You should specify the data types using *bindValue* or *bindParam*:

```
$query->bindValue(1, (int) $_GET['category'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindValue(2, $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: @Pitor:If I am not wrong,it means if I have strings only ,then no worries I can directly use `$query->execute(array(string1,string2,string3,string4))`. The only care needs to be taken when I have non-strings and thus use binding specifying their type

Answer (score 0):

**First solution:**
As stated in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10014200/1311025

- Disable emulated prepares (the MySQL driver has a bug/feature that
  will make it quote numeric arguments):

`$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);`

- Use individual bind params with the integer casting option:

`$comments->bindParam(1, $post, PDO::PARAM_STR);`
`$comments->bindParam(2, (int)$min, PDO::PARAM_INT);`
`$comments->bindParam(3, (int)$min, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

---

**Another solution:**
As its going to be always an integer, you can avoid more problems with the PDO variable binding, and use [`intval`](https://www.php.net/intval) to retrieve the integer representation of the `$start` variable, thus adding the same security validation that is added with the variable binding.

```
$start=150;
$integerStart = intval($start);
$sql='SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category=? LIMIT '.$integerStart.', 5';
$query=$con->prepare($sql)
$query->execute(array($_GET['category']));
```